# Populate table in jqgrid with objects list from Action in java

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, struts

I´m working on a Struts application and I need to populate a table in jqGrid with a list of objects.

I don´t want to use ajax for populate the table, I want to pass in the request the list of objects and in JSP generate the table with it.

How I can do it??

Searching I found a question with my same problem: http://www.coderanch.com/t/549822/Struts/fill-jqgrid-java-object-list

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i use JSON to pass the data across the request from Java to Javascript

In Struts Action I do that

```
List<Object> dataList = Service.getData();
request.setAttribute("dataList", new Gson().toJson(dataList));
```

Then in Javascript code in JSP I do an eval of JSON value and transform the string passed into an array:

```
<table id="tableExample"></table>

<script>

$("#tableExample").jqGrid({ 
    datatype: "local", 
    height: 250, 
    data: eval('<%= request.getAttribute("dataList") %>'),
    colNames:['col1','col2', 'col3', 'col4'], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'a1', index:'a1', width:150, align:"right", sorttype:"float"}, 
        {name:'a2', index:'a2', width:150, align:"right", sorttype:"float"}, 
        {name:'a3', index:'a3', width:150, align:"center", sorttype:"date", formatter:'date', formatoptions:{"srcformat":"d/m/Y","newformat":"d/m/Y"}}, 
        {name:'a4', index:'a4', width:150, align:"center", sorttype:"date", formatter:'date', formatoptions:{"srcformat":"d/m/Y","newformat":"d/m/Y"}}
    ], 
    caption: "Table Example"
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't posted any details of the JavaScript code which create jqGrid. So I try just guess what you currently do and what you can do to fix the described problem. I suggest that you try to use `datatype: "json"`, `loadonce: true` and the following `jsonReader`:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    repeatitems: false
}
```

If there are exist the column of the grid which contains unique information like primary key or which is just unique in every row of the grid then you should add in `jsonReader` additional property like `id: "columName"`, where `"columName"` is the name of the column with unique information.

Comment: @AlexCuervo: You should post the JavaScript code which creates the jqGrid. The description what you want to do is not enough to solve the problem. Moreover if you have the data *on the server side*  which you plan to use for the grid then the usage of Ajax will typically be the best choice.